# Unable to select input elements in dialog title in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I added my code here - http://jsfiddle.net/Cvf2F/3/ - any idea why I wasn't able to select the select/input element in the title area of this simple dialog in Firefox? I found out that adding draggable: false will make this work in Chrome, and this is not working in my firefox.

```
$('<div>Hello world!</div>').dialog({
 title: '<select><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option><option>D</option></select><input value="value">', 
 draggable: false
});​
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this really a known firefox issue?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is for you to remove the title bar of the dialog, since it does not work on firefox.

`<div id="StatusDialog" title="Dialog Title"></div>`

```
var data = "<select><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option><option>D</option></select><input value='value'>"

$("#StatusDialog").html(data)

$("#StatusDialog").dialog({
    draggable: false});

$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

Currently the select is blocked by some styling that is applied to the elements, that blocks the options to appearing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im still thinking if this is really the case, because it seems that I cannot select the input element too.

Comment: Yes, you are able to select both using the code I provided. http://jsfiddle.net/felipeclopes/ujwaj/

Comment: Saw it, thanks. But the title area was removed. What I'm looking for is the solution in the title area - like in my example. Else, everything is working (as expected) if in the content area.